# Word for non-malicious heckling

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word for non-malicious heckling, as when an audience member shouts something at the performer/speaker, but the statement isn't aggressive or attacking them in any way. 
(Brief, unsolicited audience participation.)

I have seen 'heckling' used as a blanket term for this, but without context the connotations of the word are negative.

Comment: *Slagging* in my dialect, but I think its connotations are more sharply negative in some other places and it is unknown in yet others.

Comment: A not-so-common locution--although it used to be quite common--is the good-natured expression "Hear, hear," meaning ""Listen to what's being said, because I agree with it and second the motion." It's another way of saying "Amen!", or "I agree," or "So be it."

Comment: @Jon Hanna: "slagging" is stronger than "heckling" in my dialect.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion yeah I thought so. *Ribbing* would cover much of what *slagging* means here, but not quite so applicable to heckling. It's worth considering that some performers dislike "good natured" heckling more than aggressive heckling; they find it just as distracting, but if they tell the person to piss off they look like the bad guy.

Comment: @JonHanna Please present *rib* as an answer, not just as a comment. It is the best answer so far, IMO. *Josh* and *tease* are also good answers. All of these express good-natured mocking or making fun of something/someone playfully.

Comment: @Drew I think *Banter* as already offered in an answer is superior to *rib*. Indeed, it's the word that was on the tip of my tongue when I first saw this question, and could only think of *rib*.

Comment: In three words: spontaneous audience participation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Banter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/banter): The playful and friendly exchange of teasing remarks

or

[Badinage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/badinage): Humourous or witty conversation

Comment: Maybe **repartee** if it's good natured and the speaker retorts.

Comment: Banter was exactly what I had in mind, and repartee is a good, less colloquial alternative.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your example if this falls in this category, but there is a style of interaction between speaker and audience named *Call and Response*, which Collins defines as "a form of interaction between a speaker and one or more listeners, in which every utterance of the speaker elicits a verbal or non-verbal response from the listener or listeners."

It is particularly characteristic of African and African Diaspora cultures, and many people who are used to call-and-response settings will continue the response side even in situations where the speaker may not be soliciting or expecting that form of audience interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the following may be relevant, although several of the verbs have slightly negative connotations.
• *[chaff](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chaff#Verb)*, “To use light, idle language by way of fun or ridicule; to banter”
• *[josh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/josh#Verb)*, “To tease someone in a kindly fashion”
• *[needle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needle#Verb)*, “To tease in order to provoke; to poke fun at”
• *[quiz](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quiz#Verb)*, “(archaic) To hoax; to chaff or mock with pretended seriousness of discourse; to make sport of, as by obscure questions”
• *[kibitz](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kibitz#Verb)*, “To give unsolicited or unwanted advice or make unhelpful or idle comments”

One who kibitzes is a *[kibitzer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kibitzer#Noun)*, “A person who offers unsolicited views, advice, or criticism”.  Kibitzing during a speech is indeed a form of non-malicious heckling, although the speaker might prefer to do without extraneous advice.

Comment: +1 for joshing, this is the first word that came to mind when I read the question and is the only one I've seen that is really both one-way and not negative.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm including this as a separate answer because it covers an entirely different situation)

*Outburst* - a sudden, unplanned verbal interruption, usually motivated by a strong emotion.

Answer (score 0):

Providing [**laudation**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/laudation?&path=/)

Giving [**accolades**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accolades?&path=/)

Chiming [**kudos**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kudos?&path=/)

Giving [**approbation**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/approbation?&path=/)

- Fanfare
- Hurrahs
- Exultation
- Encouragement
  ...

Answer (score 0):

My favorite term for this though is [talking smack](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talking%20%20smack).  It is certainly slang but it is more modern and used in America.  You talk smack to friends.  You can playfully talk smack to a comedian on stage.